# Green manzanilla olives - the brine has turned black

Tags: olive

I opened this jar 3 weeks ago. I had written the date on it when I opened it. I just took it out to use some green olives a salad and the brine has turned inky black. The olive are sort of taking on that color. I grabbed a fresh jar to compare of the same olive and the brine in the unopened jar is clear. I'm throwing them out. It really looks like someone poured coffee in the jar. I've never seen anything like this happen before.
Is there any explanation? Were these olives safe to use? Or did something go wrong? They are in a glass jar, not a can. The coating of the lid looks intact and no mold growing anywhere. These best by date is 2024, a couple years away.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Not anything I've seen, but throwing them out was probably the right move.